# autoclose html tag on </ in notepad++

Tags: html, plugins, notepad++

I've been using notepad++ for a while now and I've encountered a problem with auto close when it comes to different html tags.

I'm wondering if it is possible to auto close the nearest tag when writing

```
</
```

(like it does in dreamweaver) instead of the tag being auto closed when you write

```
> (at the beginning tag for example <html(>)<-- it auto closes
 the tag here and it includes also comment tags which makes
it look like this:
<!----></!----->)
```

I've tried TextFX and I've not managed to fix it through that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to do it via TextFX settings? If you tick there the option `+ Autoclose XHTML/XML <Tag>`, each time you close the bracket of an opening tag, it will create a closing tag. For example, if you type `<div>`, the moment you finish typing `>`, the editor will automatically create `</div>` right next to it. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes i know that, but the thing is, it does the same with comment tags so it looks like this: <!----></!----> and that is kind of annoying, the thing that I want to change it so that when I write <div></ , it should close the tag instead of when I write >